# cannot connect to my nginx server from remote machine

Tags: centos, nginx, django

I thought that it's iptables problem.. but it seems not.
I really have no idea about this situation.

I'm getting a server hosting(CentOS).
I installed Nginx + Django and nginx uses 8080 port.
A domain is connected to the server.

When I executed "wget [domain]:8080/[app name]/" in the server,
it worked.
Of course, "wget 127.0.0.1:8080/[app name]/" has no problem.
(wget [server ip]:8080/[app name]/, either)

However, from other computers, connecting was failed.
(message says, no route)

I checked my firewall setting.
I excuted these commands.

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8080 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
 /etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

I don't really understand all options of commands and I think there were useless commands, but I just tried all googled iptables settings.

But still I cannot connect to my server.
What should I check, first?

I don't know this is important, but add to this post.
On 80 port, an apache server is running.
It works fine, I can connect to apache from other computers.
There is DB connecting issue, (PHP to MySQL) but I think that it is just PHP coding bug.

please excuse my low-level English.
I'm not native English speaker..
but I tried to explane well as far as possible.
Thank you for reading this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shut down your fw, flush all rules and retry your remote connections

- if you can connect -> adjust your firewall
- if you cant connect -> ajdust your routing

you can see check with `tcpdump port 8080` on your server, if packages are arriving.

Comment: Why I didn't try to turn off firewall? I stoped to think about fw, just considered about other things. Yes, it worked when I turned off. I think there was a mistake on iptables setting.

Comment: I refreshed all setting, and everything is all right. I really appreciate. I cannot understand why I didn't try that. I was lost my mind..

Answer (score 1):

If you have executed the sequence of command you wrote, I think no rule has been applied because you have restarted iptables without saving the new settings.

Try to add the following rule in the iptables file /etc/sysconfig/iptables (check there are no other rules on port 8080):

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

or with the following commands:

```
 iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
 iptables-save
```

Restart iptables:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

Now you should see the rule running this command:

```
root@centos01 sysconfig]# iptables -L -n | grep 8080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8080
```

Try to connect from remote hosts

Comment: I followed your guide, and the result of `iptables -L -n | grep 8080` is `ACCEPT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 state NEW tcp dpt:8080` that is just like you wrote. But still the same problem.
For following your guide, I deleted one line from iptables file. I think that the setting was already saved.